# Call PHP function by name from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript function that's executed on a button click and I have an included file containing all my PHP functions. One of the PHP functions returns me an array of filenames encoded as a JSON object. I'd like to call this function from my Javascript function so that I can use the array. I know I can call a PHP file which would run but in this case I only want to call one specific named method.

I tried the following but couldn't get it to work (Console error: Unexpected < )

```javascript
function getPHPArray(){
    var picArray;
    picArray = <?php getPicArrayJson(); ?>;
}
```

Can this be done using XMLHttpRequest or do I need to find another method? (If reasonably possible I'd prefer straight Javascript over JQuery but I can use JQuery if it makes this significantly easier)

If so how?

My PHP method is as follows:

```php
function getPicArrayJson(){
    global $fileArrayString;
    If (!empty($fileArrayString)){
        echo json_encode($fileArrayString);
    }
}
```

My JavaScript so far:

```javascript
function getPHPArray(){
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}   
xmlhttp.open("POST", "phpFunctions.php?name=getPicArrayJson", true);   
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the misunderstanding so that I can reformulate my approach/question?

Comment: Seems the downvoters and closers on the question are too lazy to bother adding a comment.

Comment: First make sure the php you actually call returns valid json

Comment: Renamed my variables for clarity - is that what you meant or should I be using return over echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a [Remote Procedure Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). For use with PHP, I'd check out [JSON-RPC PHP](http://jsonrpcphp.org/).

---

Anyway, here's a basic way you can do it without much complexity to your app. You will have to make an ajax request to the server. The idea for you here is to use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func).

```
call_user_func("getPicArrayJson");
```

You can use

```
call_user_func($_POST["name"]);
```

But I **highly recommend** that you only allow certain functions to be called

---

**phpFunctions.php**

```php
$allowed_functions = array("getPicArrayJson");
$name              = $_POST["name"];

function getPicArrayJson() {
  $pics = array("1.jpg", "2.jpg");
  return json_encode($pics);
}

// legal function
if (in_array($name, $allowed_functions)) {
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  $json = call_user_func($name);
  die($json);
}

// invalid access
else {
  // Error 400
}
```

Then do you Ajax request per normal

```js
...
xmlhttp.open("POST", "phpFunctions.php?name=getPicArrayJson", true);   
xmlhttp.send();
```

---

**ps** my own two cents, I would use a `GET` request for this. Following [RESTful API conventions for web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services), a `POST` request would only be used to create a new element.

Comment: Why the downvotes on this answer? Upvoted for attempting to answer my question - thanks! It seems this is purely PHP side though? How would my JavaScript call look?

Comment: I'm trying this solution at the moment - can you explain why you'd prefer GET over POST for this scenario?

Comment: Passing user input to `call_user_func` that has not been sanitized opens up *huge* security loopholes. Server admins would have nightmares about this type of code.

Comment: @AlexW, did you miss the whole part of my post where I instruct db679 to sanitize the input?

Comment: @db579, I added a note about `GET` vs `POST` and provided a link for you to read up on. I hope this helps.

Comment: @naomik how about dropping `call_user_func` to avoid the overhead of the lookup and simply call the requested function if within an array of allowed functions? eg `$func =$_POST["name"]; $func(); `

Comment: @melc, nah. I wanted db579 to see the flexibility provided with `call_user_func`. For example, an generic func, static  method, or a instance method can all be called using `call_user_func`. It has a nice accompaniment, `call_user_func_array`, which I'm sure he would see while reading the docs, too. Both of which I believe to be far more readable than wretched [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) that you're proposing.